# select form error populating optgroup and options from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, select, html-entities

I've created a select list with the optgroups and options coming from mysql. When I tried the following code, this error comes up, although the optgroup is correct, but options show the error. Can anyone help me fix it please? Thanks.

```
<select id="lr-cat" name="category">
            <option value="0"></option>
            <?php

            $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "database");
            $results = $mysqli->query('SELECT subcat_id, subcat_name, subcategories.cat_id, cat_name FROM subcategories INNER JOIN categories ON subcategories.cat_id=categories.cat_id');

            $categories = array();
            while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
                $cat_name = $row['cat_name'];
                if (!array_key_exists($cat_name, $categories)){
                    $categories[$cat_name] = array();}

                $categories[$cat_name][] = array($row['subcat_id'], $row['subcat_name']);
            }

            mysqli_close($con);
            ?>
            <?php foreach ($categories as $cat_name => $subcategories): ?>

                <optgroup label="<?php echo htmlentities($cat_name); ?>">

                    <?php foreach ($subcategories as $subcat_name): ?>

                        <option value=$subcat_id><?php echo htmlentities($subcat_name); ?></option> <!--line 128-->

                    <?php endforeach; ?>

                </optgroup>

            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
```

Error

> Warning: htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
>   in line 128

Comment: The Warning means that `$subcat_name` isn't a String! You could echo it before you use it and than you can see whats in the variable!

Comment: the options doesn't work if I remove the empty [],only show one option when theres more, so I can't delete it. Do you know any other way to do the optgroups?

Comment: Im not 100% sure but did you tried this: `htmlentities($subcat_name[$subcat_name]);`

Comment: neither works, the first one just complete doesn't show any options and the second one shows up error with illegal offset type warning